# Props are undefined in react when passing through <Route/>

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

My props are undnefined in react. Here's my app.js line of code:

```
<Route
            exact
            path='/solutions/standard'
            category={'standard'}
            component={Solutions}
          />
```

and here is my componenet:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

const Solutions = ({category}) => {
    const pageTitle = `${
      category.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + category.substring(1)
    } Solutions`;
  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>{pageTitle}</title>
      </Helmet>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Solutions;
```

but I get this as a render error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
```

Basically the category prop is undefined for whatever reason.

Comment: what version of react router are you using ? + the problem is not with react but with the way you render your component. What is category in this case?

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI, catagory in this case is as you can see: 'standard', This is propbably the latest version of react router

Comment: alright then don't use component but pass it as children to the route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following syntax:

```
<Route
            exact
            path='/solutions/standard'
            render={() => <Solutions category='standard' />}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or this:

```
<Route path='/solutions/standard'>
  <Solutions category='standard' />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs because you are not passing any prop to your component.

To pass it either use the render prop or pass your component as children to the Route component.

```
<Route exact path='/solutions/standard'>
  <Solutions category='solutions' />
</Route>
```